# Dark mode on Salary Calculator not rendering well

Tags: bug, dark-mode, salary-calculator

When you have dark mode enabled, the side menu of the page [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) still renders in white. As far as I searched, the CSS file **all.min.css** override its own rule and the rule on **primary.css** rule (`background-color: var(--white);`)

[image: css rule overriding]

[image: print of dark mode on salary calculator page]

Also, the same **all.min.css** file appears to be hiding the "popups" from the upper toolbar. The print below it's the **Recent inbox messages** div.

[image]

Comment: If you need this urgently fixing now, you can pop this into your bookmarks and use this: `javascript:document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "var(--white) !important";` This should fix it