# High contrast mode beta

Tags: discussion, design, accessibility, high-contrast-mode

Today we’re introducing a beta of high contrast mode. You can enable it in [your user preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/).

[image: Settings]

This setting will allow us to make the site more accessible for folks who need a bit more contrast without sacrificing aesthetics for those who don’t. Its goal is to make Stack Overflow meet or exceed [WCAG AAA contrast criteria](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-enhanced) and more importantly, improve Stack Overflow for people with visual impairments. If you think you’d benefit from a high contrast interface, we’d love to know if this helps.

It’s available in both light or dark mode. Like dark mode, this was made possible by our design system [Stacks](https://www.stackoverflow.design/). It will be available everywhere dark mode is. Currently, that’s Stack Overflow (And its localized sites in Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, and Spanish), Teams, and Enterprise.

[image: Light]

[image: Dark]

I’m sure there will be lots of areas that can be improved. Expect instances where high contrast isn’t applied properly or at all. If you find any of those, please add them as an answer here with some details about your operating system and your browser.

Comment: Is this a bug? [Badges have become light in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411819)

Comment: Why are Meta FAQs on the main site in the screenshot?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Our local development environment actually uses meta as its test database. I can update the screenshot if it's confusing.

Comment: Like this, but contrast is extra low for Teams completed items: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeVxM.png

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE we've shipped a fix for the Teams completed items contrast. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Nice for AMOLED screens!

Comment: lol, judging from the answers, I am one of the last non-dark SO user :P

Comment: Oof. The contrast is far too high in multiple places. There is only a 3:1 requirement for UI critical components. Other than that, borders, hr elements, etc. which are non critical, there is no defined contrast ratio. https://webaim.org/articles/contrast/

Comment: Any chance of getting a darker mode that doesn't have this high contrast? The dark+high contrast is a way better dark color than the regular dark, but I don't need the bright parts to be brighter also.

Answer (score 42):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Low contrast of post interaction buttons (upvote/downvote, bookmark, history) in dark mode.

1. Open any question.

The buttons are almost impossible to see in dark mode since they are dark grey on black background.

[image: Image of the post buttons in high contrast dark mode. Very hard to see them as they blend into the black background]

For comparison, here is the regular dark mode:

[image: Image of the post buttons in regular dark mode. They are clearly distinguishable from the background]

Comment: A fix for this has gone out and these buttons should have usable contrast now. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I don't have this mode enabled :

[image]

But I got issue with dark theme on google chrome, I can't read badge :

[image]

Except when I put my mouse on hover:

[image]

Comment: How can I add the "bug" tag on my answer ?

Comment: with `[meta-tag:bug]`

Comment: This bug is a byproduct of messing with badge CSS for high contrast mode (but not necessarily _because_ of high contrast mode). We have a fix that'll be going out in the next release. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411824/652353

Comment: Same problem in high contrast dark mode: https://i.imgur.com/N2j3quG.png

Comment: We shipped a fix for this late last week. Thank you for reporting this!

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

### Very hard to tell difference between visited and unvisited links in question list

1. Open a question list, for example a tag like like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).
2. Open one of the questions in the list.

This will mark the link as visited. However, it is very hard to tell which one is or is not visited as the difference between their colours in high contrast dark mode is very small. Here is an example where the second link is visited:

[image: Image of two questions. The difference in the colour of their titles is very small.]

For comparison, this is normal dark mode for the same questions:

[image: Image of two questions. The difference in the colour of their titles is easy to distinguish.]

Answer (score 20):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Low contrast of scores of questions with accepted answers in the Related menu

1. Open a question.
2. Look at the Related questions on the right.

The score is in white and if the question has an accepted answer, the score gets a light green background. This makes it borderline illegible.

[image: Screenshot showing almost illegible scores of questions]

For comparison, profile shows the scores of bookmarked questions with accepted answers in dark numbers while the scores of questions without accepted answers are light. This looks a lot more legible on a green background.

[image: Screenshot of the "Bookmarks| section of a profile. The scores are legible.]

[Related similar issue with score text in the profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411825)

Comment: This is now fixed in production. Good catch!

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

While the contrast in "Activity → All actions" for absolute dates is fine, it's a bit low for the relative ones.

Light mode ([fails all WCAG standards](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=DDDFE2&bcolor=FFFFFF)):

[image]

Dark mode ([fails all WCAG standards as well](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=1D2022&bcolor=000000)):

[image]

Comment: We shipped a fix for this issue late last week, but I'm not 100% sure we got all instances of this specific relative date contrast issue. I think we're good, but let us know if you come across this issue again. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Inconsistency and low contrast of how scores are shown for followed posts in the profile

1. Go to your user profile.
2. Go to the Following tab.

The followed posts where there is an accepted answer have light letters on light green background. Posts where there is no accepted answers have light letters with no (the default dark) background. The light on light green is hard to read:

[image: Image showing the hard to read scores for followed questions]

This is inconsistent with the following tabs in the profile which show information in a similar way:

- the "Questions" tab:

  [image: Image showing the scores in the "Questions" tab in the profile. The ones with accepted answers have dark text on green background. Ones without accepted answers have green text without a background and a green outline around the score box.]
- the "Bookmarks" tab:

  [image: Image showing the scores in the "Bookmarks" tab in the profile. The ones with accepted answers have dark text on green background. Ones without accepted answers have green text without a background and a green outline around the score box.]
- the "Bounties" tab:

  [image: Image showing the scores in the "Bounties" tab in the profile. The ones with accepted answers have dark text on green background. Ones without accepted answers have green text without a background and a green outline around the score box.]

[A similar issue with score text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411823)

Comment: I believe this should now be fixed. Let us know if we missed a spot!

Answer (score 10):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

I would really appreciate a higher-contrast color for showing up deleted posts in your flag history:

[image]

Or perhaps the [Deleted] tag on deleted followed posts:

[image]

It looks OK in the screenshot, but you'll have to actually go to the flag history to get it.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The filter button in review queues has low contrast when it's pressed.

| Light Mode | Dark Mode |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Light mode] | [image: dark mode] |

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The "Unwatch tag" button on tag pages ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)) has insufficient contrast in both light mode:

[image: "Unwatch tag" button with black text on a dark blue background]

And also in dark mode:

[image: "Unwatch tag" button with white text on a light blue background]

The "Filter" button has the same problem:

[image: "Filter" button in light mode with black text on a dark blue background] [image: "Filter" button in dark mode with white text on a light blue background]

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)  [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Low contrast for badge counts in top bar in light mode on Teams:

[image: User icon, reputation, and two badge counts - silver and bronze, both dull colors on a black background]

In fact, it looks lower-contrast than with high contrast mode disabled:

[image: ser icon, reputation, and two badge counts - silver and bronze, both bright colors on a medium gray background]

Comment: Your "light mode" looks very dark ;) But.. I don't know about the top bar in Teams.

Comment: @Scratte the top bar in Teams is dark in both light & dark modes.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Hard to distinguish the question author name in comments.

1. Open a question where the author commented on any of the posts within.

For me, at least, it is impossible to tell which user is the question author or not in high contrast dark mode:

[image: Image showing two comments. First from user "Angry John"; the second from user "T.J. Crowder"]

Perhaps somebody else can tell which of the two users above is the OP but not me.

Here is normal dark mode for comparison:

[image: Image showing two comments. First from user "Angry John" who has a distinguishable background set on their name; the second from user "T.J. Crowder"]

Comment: This is true in light mode as well with contrast enabled

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The button for adding an ignored tag has no padding at all:

[image]

Comment: This has been fixed! Thank you for reporting it!

Comment: @DanCormier I saw, a week ago in fact ;), thanks for the ping though

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Low contrast of notification which allows a live reload

1. Go to a tag like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) (picked [top 3 most popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular)).
2. Wait until a question is posted.

A notification appears which can be clicked in order to live load the questions.

The background of this notification is almost indistinguishable from the normal background of the page in high contrast dark mode.

[image: Image shows a notification which reads "36 questions with new activity" but the background of it is hard to see.]

For comparison, here is the notification in normal dark mode:

[image: Image shows a notification which reads "2 questions with new activity". The notification has a visible background which makes it seem like a button.]

This is the same for other notifications of this kind like ones showing new answers to questions or edits to posts. However, the steps here describe the easiest way to get this notification.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Low contrast between watched and unwatched tag questions using dark mode (light mode is acceptable):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Low contrast on links relative to the surrounding text in light mode:

[image: "Looking for more? Browse the complete list of questions, or popular tags. Help us answer unanswered questions." in black text on a white background, with "complete list of questions", "popular tags", and "unanswered questions" in very dark blue text that is nearly indistinguishable from black.]

(there are three links in that text)

Spot the links ([solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln3A9.png)):

[image: Screenshot of the ask a question page with many links in dark blue in the middle of black text]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Enabling high contrast mode reduces contrast ratio of "Used by thousands of organizations around the globe" text on [Teams signup page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/create/free) (from 2.14 to 1.28 —though neither meets [accessibility standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Perceivable/Color_contrast)).

[image: "Used by thousands of organizations around the globe" in dark gray on a darker gray background]

Compare to normal mode:

[image: "Used by thousands of organizations around the globe" in medium-light gray on a medium gray background]

A similar issue occurs in light mode (contrast ratio 1.26):

[image: "Used by thousands of organizations around the globe" in light gray on a white background]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Issue is very similar to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411825/4826457).

The recommended badge tag has light text on green background. It would be easier to read with dark font color.

[image: Recommended badge]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Low contrast on "Read more" link in privacy policy announcement banner in light mode:

[image: Banner reading "We changed our privacy policy. Read more." on a dark gray background with "Read more" in dark blue text]

And in dark mode:

[image: Banner reading "We changed our privacy policy. Read more." on a very light gray background with "Read more" in light blue text]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Enabling high-contrast mode reduces text contrast on [Press page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/press) in dark mode (compare to [normal mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHAXQ.png)):

[image: Press page with cards having light blue text on a light gray background]

And light mode (compare to [normal mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcxkO.png)):

[image: Press page with cards having dark blue text on a medium gray background]

<sup>And despite appearances, I have correctly labeled the light mode/dark mode images...</sup>

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)  [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

"Take a tour" button on [Company pages](https://stackoverflow.com/company) has insufficient contrast in dark mode (it's fine in light mode).

[image: "Take a tour" button with white text on a light blue background]

The "Learn more" button at the bottom of the ["Work here" page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) is similarly broken:

[image: Screenshot: "Life at Stack Overflow Learn more about our core values, benefits, and commitment to diversity, equity, and inclusion." with a "Learn more" button below it with a white outline, white text, and a light blue background]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The upvote/flag button next to comments is barely visible.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[On this page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/customer-success), the text under the green titles is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Unanswered (my tags)" link in the "More" popover has low contrast if it's disabled (that is, if the user has no watched tags).

Light mode ([fails all WCAG standards](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=D6D9DC&bcolor=FFFFFF)):

[image]

Dark mode ([fails all WCAG standards as well](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=232629&bcolor=000000)):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In light mode, bottom corners of "Products" dropdown are light while the rest of the border is dark:

[image: Screenshot of a dropdown with a black border and grey curved bottom corners]

The opposite problem occurs in dark mode:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[On the Employer Branding page](https://stackoverflow.com/talent/en/branding), the "Source:" text is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

On the Talent page, there's a similar issue:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The gravatar within the flair in the side menu seems to have gotten a background color.

[image: Flair in side menu]

The gravatar in header and posts do not have these. This looks inconsistent.

[image: Flair in post]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Jobs/Search: the search/location icons are barely visible.

[image: Jobs - Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Site Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources): traffic source legend labels aren't visible. (On the right of the 3 squares, there should be visible labels)

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Tag Synonyms: the like/dislike buttons are hard to see when unselected.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Similar to [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411837/3151675): highlighted and not highlighted jobs are difficult to distinguish.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[On this page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/calculate/speed-to-market), the "Email me the copy of ROI Calculator" title is not easy to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Site Analytics/Traffic Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources): the tooltip appearing when tapping on the second bar chart is barely readable.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[On this page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives-on-stack-overflow), the "See how Collectives on Stack Overflow supports your teams’ goals" text is barely readable.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)... or possibly [dark-pattern](/questions/tagged/dark-pattern)

[On this page](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/solutions), the asterisk text is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: It is also, as has been pointed out elsewhere in the past, confusing copyright and trademark...

Answer (score 2):

Profile: the reputation graph is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue in light mode]
[image: screenshot of the issue in dark mode]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The Collective icon for posts has its left edge cropped down.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Jobs/Match preferences: the text fields are barely visible.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Jobs sidebar: the Relocation text and the icon next to it are hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The number badge next to Bountied is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: N.B. this is only on the homepage, not the /questions list

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[The Salary Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) has a white background.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: This is probably related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403012/dark-mode-on-salary-calculator-not-rendering-well . The dark mode without the contrast enabled doesn't work in that page correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/create) looks horrible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[Site Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics): the "downvotes" text is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[Teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams): In Light mode, the "Features for large orgs" button is hard to see. (I know that the background is dark, but trust me, this is Light mode)

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On locked posts, the "Comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews" text is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Ask Question page: the "Hide formatting tips" button is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Jobs sidebar: the arrow icon next to "View more jobs..." is hard to see.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

Dark mode with high contrast:

Profile → *Settings* → *Preferences* → *Labs* → *"Pending"*

It's hard to call it contrast at all when it's white text on a light yellow background.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In Jobs, the "Visa sponsor" text is barely visible.

[image: Jobs screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Ignored Tags: the highlighted item of the list is hard to read.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: I disagree; it seems pretty easy to read to me; white text on black background is the most contrast you could possibly have.

Comment: @TylerH perhaps OP meant the white text on orange background( highlighted item)

Comment: @TylerH Yes, Suraj Rao is right