# Dark theme link colors

Tags: feature-request, dark-mode

Since the introduction of the dark theme on Stack Overflow, I've used a custom theme modification (on a work computer) that made the links grayscale instead of blue (and the icons incidentally too). I kept the original blue styling of the Stack Overflow dark theme on a home computer to see what kind of effect it has on my interaction with the templating.

In my own personal, possibly biased opinion, it makes it easier for me to interact, read and glean the information from the gray-colored links at work more than the blue-colored links at home. I've given myself since the [dark theme was introduced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits) early 2020 to see if I would get used to the blue, to see if it really made a difference.

Most of the time it didn't, but I do find that I have difficulty reading the question titles fully because of the color blue. My mind kind of switches off halfway through question titles, and other links go into some sort of ignore box in my head after seeing the first two words. This is not an effect that I have with gray colored links.

I'm not the only one that prefers more contrast, but the [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/395973#395973) on the above-mentioned thread has been in [status-review since May 11 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/396655/39).

I've been waiting for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/214343), but now I thought to stir the pot a bit and give [this feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/395973#395973) request a renewed chance:

**Give the link colors more contrast instead of hazy blue that fades into the background.**

Here you can see the default blue links vs the gray links I use side by side.

[image: Color schemes side by side]

The CSS I use to enhance my dark mode experience

```css
.subcommunity-avatar.s-avatar {
   filter: grayscale(1);
}
.subcommunity-google-cloud.s-avatar,
.subcommunity-go.s-avatar {
    filter: invert(1) grayscale(1);
}
body {
    --theme-link-color: #ddd !important;
    --theme-link-color-hover: #ccc !important;
    --theme-link-color-visited: #bbb !important;
}
```

Comment: More like [high contrast mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411820/6083675)? (Personally, I think every mode should be high contrast, or at least high enough contrast.)

Comment: No, high contrast is too extreme, i just need a bit more contrast in the dark mode link colours

Comment: I have to note that the current blue color meets the accessibility AA standard (5.32, not even far from AAA) [which, now that I revisited the original FR has already been pointed out, sorry]. Frankly, I am not in favor of links being any color but blue for unvisited links (being the convention from times immemorial), but your feature request actually makes them *more* accessible by meeting the AAA with whopping 10.14 points, so in favor of the proposal too. Will likely need another 6 to 8, though