# Announcing Design Accessibility Updates on SO

Tags: discussion, accessibility, announcement

**Update**

When we announced the accessibility initiative we had originally stated that the changes would only only be rolling out on SO and on the Teams product. Once the work on this began we realized it made sense for some changes to be deployed network wide. We also encountered some issues around color hacks, legacy code, etc.—we have decided that we are going to put a pause on this initiative and future updates so we can sort that out.

Some network wide color contrast changes that were deployed last week and we’ve [posted these changes on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382079/recent-color-contrast-changes-and-accessibility-updates) if you’d like to see them.

---

**TL;DR:** We’re kicking off an initiative focusing on improving accessibility on SO and Teams. We underwent an audit of design areas on the site that are not visually accessible to everyone, and are focusing on deploying fixes for the highest-priority issues over the next couple of months. The majority of these changes may not be noticeable to the majority of users, but we want to be transparent about the updates and why we feel they are necessary.

### Roadmap

During the first half of 2022, we worked with a third-party accessibility audit firm to create a full audit report of issues on our site that don’t meet the accessibility standards we’d like to hold ourselves to. We are focusing on fixing the most critical issues over the course of the next few months.

Most of the changes will be minor, and you may not even notice them. They are primarily focused around:

- improving color contrast;
- fixing areas of the site where alt text is missing;
- ensuring that some site elements that are currently not accessible by keyboard alone are made accessible;
- and updating text and navigation lists so that all characters are distinguishable.

For these minor modifications, we will not be making a separate meta announcement when each individual change rolls out, but we will be making periodic posts throughout the initiative to share updates around the changes we’ve made. If we find that any changes will be more visible or impactful, we will make dedicated posts to announce those. After this phase of the initiative has completed, we’ll post a summary of all the changes we made and address whether other changes will be made in the near future.

### FAQ

**What site(s) and product(s) will this initiative support?**

The current initiative is focused on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and the [Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/) product. However, where it makes sense we will be pushing some changes that will be network wide.

**Will changes that are SO/Teams only get rolled out to the other Stack Exchange sites?**

For any changes that we’re unable to push network wide at the moment our goal is to eventually roll them out network-wide. We don’t have a current timeline for that rollout. If, by the end of this initiative, we have mapped out a timeline to do so, we will share that in the wrap-up post.

**Why is this happening?**

A core part of our mission is that our products and tools empower people to find what they need to develop technology. That’s why we’re focusing on improving accessibility on the most critical areas of our site. We want the platform to be a space where everyone can easily access the information they are seeking.

**How can I provide feedback?**

We will be monitoring this post and the separate meta announcements for larger roll outs for responses up until we make the wrap-up post towards the end of the year. If you have feedback about any changes or want to report any bugs that may be related to this initiative, please post them as an answer under this question (one issue per answer, please). If you are reporting a bug, please provide any steps needed to reliably reproduce the issue you are experiencing, including the browsers and devices where you are encountering the error.

Comment: Does this also include alt text on images in future announcements on SO, and on the blog in particular? Or is the blog not part of the push?

Comment: Are the smaller changes going to be announced at all? You could just have a single post that you edit those into.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine the blog isn't part of this push.

Comment: @Laurel yes we do plan on sharing the smaller changes too we just won't be having individual posts dedicated to each change in those cases.

Comment: Try to [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419586/edit) this post, and use TAB and Shift + TAB to tab between the fields. The title becomes invisible. Is this covered by the audit?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - I followed your directions and either I'm not seeing something or else the title is not disappearing for me.

Comment: @JDB [edit], tab, tab, shift+tab, shift+tab reproduces the issue for me. (The field is hidden behind the top nav bar.)

Comment: I'm lately getting blue frames around the "Follow", "Close", "Flag" links below questions when clicking on them. Does this have something to do with this? I don't see it mentioned or asked about anywhere, so I'm wondering if I'm the only one seeing this.

Comment: @mkrieger1: I've asked about it here: [Some buttons on the site are being highlighted even on mouse-click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381101/some-buttons-on-the-site-are-being-highlighted-even-on-mouse-click)

Comment: @Rosie why was this announced here and not on MSE?

Comment: @Phil looks like originally they (SE developers who were assigned for this project)  wanted to update only Stack Overflow, but they forgot the code used on SO is also used by all other Stack Exchange sites. (Which makes it easier to maintain, but impossible to do site-specific changes like they wanted here)

Comment: Lately I have been having two major accessibility problems: 1) _StackOverflow_ no longer works on the latest browsers available on *Windows XP*: *Firefox EST* and *MyPal*. 2) With often two columns of sidebar information, _StackOverflow_ is difficult to view on medium-sized 4:3 and 5:4 displays, such as the one I correctly use: 17 inches at 1280x1024.

Comment: @AntonShepelev if it hasn't been already can you post that as a new question and tag it as a bug? That we can triage it to have devs investigate .

Answer (score 65):

There are currently 53 questions tagged [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) here on Meta.SO. Many of them are yet unsolved issues regarding WCAG violations or other accessibility concerns very similar to the ones mentioned by Rosie in this post. Does this initiative include looking at those meta posts, fixing the issues and answering the posts?

Of course it is a good idea to employ a third-party accessibility audit firm, which presumably conducts a thorough audit instead of an isolated issue here and there like in the meta posts. On the other hand, the people from the firm presumably don't know about all the small details that actual users encounter when browsing Stack Overflow, so the meta posts could be a useful addition to the findings of the firm. Additionally, the meta posts concern issues that have actually affected people, so addressing them has provable practical value beyond the (commendable) goal of meeting accessibility guidelines as such.

Furthermore, the main meta has an additional [190 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility). Some of them do not concern Stack Overflow (the site), but many are applicable to all sites, including SO. Does the current initiative plan to look at those as well?

Comment: This current initiative isn't going to involve specifically looking at those posts however some of those may become irrelevant/resolved as a result so we do plan on reviewing them, later on, to see which ones are still issues and if they can be picked up in the future.

Comment: So instead of using the collective power of the community you decide to shell out big bucks to a company to basically tell you the same thing you where already told @Rosie?

Comment: @Luuklag it's all about trust, in the bottom line.

Comment: @Luuklag Accessibility development, as far as I can tell, is 100% about liability reduction. Those big bucks aren’t for experts who can tell them how to improve the site—the big bucks are for someone else to sign a piece of paper saying it’s good, so that if the site gets sued, they can point at someone else. Any improvements that happen are there solely because the consultants require them to limit their own liability risk before they’ll sign that piece of paper. Improvements in the site experience are almost entirely coincidental.

Comment: @Luuklag This isn’t about Stack Exchange per se, either—this is every site on the Internet, that I can tell. (Well, every site that bothers to care at all, which seems to be a small fraction.) And having done the work, this is almost how it **has** to be—I’ve worked on sites that wanted to actually improve things, but ended up giving up and just got the consultants to sign the piece of paper. Accessibility guidance—beyond very basic things like `alt` properties, headings, and contrast—is a complete mess and almost impossible to get confidently “right.”

Comment: @KRyan What law(s) govern website accessibility?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- In America, the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) applies to websites as much as it does to anything else. I also worked for a company that worked with veterans and had additional compliance requirements imposed by... Someone, never actually heard where they came from, per se. But compliance was considered an existential concern there.

Comment: @KRyan If you were working on something for Veterans Affairs, I believe the Rehabilitation act covers that; it requires all federal agency websites (internal and public) to comply with WCAG 2.0+ guidelines. Much more recently, the Department of Veterans Affairs Website Accessibility Act was signed into law (around 2020); that requires any websites that serve veterans to comply with accessibility guidelines as well.

Comment: @TylerH It wasn’t the VA, it was a private company that marketed itself to veterans and I guess had some kind of agreements with the DoD, VA, or both.

Comment: @KRyan Gotcha; I have not read the full text of the bill but I bet dollars to donuts it also imposes similar requirements on any private websites that serve veterans, too.

Answer (score 24):

Would the changes extend to high contrast mode?

Would the changes extend to dark mode?

Comment: color changes should be automatically updating things in dark mode as well as light. High contrast colors should also automatically update if the main color is changed. If anything looks off though when we announce changes that have been pushed if the community lets us know we'll make sure it's flagged to the right team.

Comment: @Rosie That doesn't actually address current problems exclusive to these. For example, high contrast dark mode inline code formatting [is hard to distinguish from other text](https://i.imgur.com/g1dZiMD.png) - mostly the font is different. There is technically a background but hardly noticeable. For the record, here is how it looks [in high contrast light mode](https://i.imgur.com/yBAHiXi.png) and [here is a change I've done myself](https://i.imgur.com/q9Y0l4g.png) to see it better. Would anything like that be changed or would it just be colours that are shared with other themes?

Answer (score 10):

**Include Colorblindness as part of Contrast work?**

Can you specifically call out colorblindness (protanopia, deuteranopia) as one of the factors to include when working on the contrast?

The current site is good in this area, leading me to believe you've already worked on improving this. It would be great to keep this going and not have an accidental regression.

Comment: You are correct. Color blindness is one of the areas that is addressed in contrasting work. When color and/or contrast are used to further emphasize information we focus on making sure accessibility isn't regressed for those with color blindness.

Answer (score 6):

There seem to be a lot of accessibility-related changes going on recently.  Is there a reason these are being pushed site-wide instead of added as part of some sort of accessibility mode? (cf high contrast mode)

It's my understanding that high contrast mode was specifically [introduced for WCAG compilance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411820/high-contrast-mode-beta) so it seems like that would be a logical home for some of these changes.

Comment: Accessibility features can also be useful for non-impaired users, and even if they are not useful then these changes are neutral (if the implementation is done right). Therefore, implementing this site-wide does not have a disadvantage. Conversely, implementing a separate mode has the disadvantage of needing to maintain yet another mode, and also that this mode may not be easily discoverable for users that are unfamiliar with the site.

Comment: @Marijn For invisible features (like alt text) what you are saying makes sense, but not so much for visible features like high contrast or the re-design of up/down vote buttons that was recently tested. Presumably some users will welcome the changes while others will find them distasteful, otherwise why not just force everyone to use high-contrast mode?  As far as making an alt mode accessible, a WCAG compliant button with the properties outlined here (high contrast, keyboard accessible, ect.) should be sufficient. It could be put right next to the log in button.

Comment: WCAG is well intended, but its guidance on contrast is insufficient, allowing designers to accost users with low contrast text. The WCAG folks seem to understand this, and they want to come up with a better system for V3, but last time I looked there still weren't any great proposals. It's impossible to quantify contrast given variation in monitors and ambient lighting. Contrast checking tools are often wrong because they oversimplify the calculation or are applied in unsupported situations. The current 4.5:1 and 7:1 ratios are rather arbitrary and not supported by the cited research.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Highlight of keyboard selected posts no longer visible in high contrast dark mode.

When using the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>J</kbd> for down, <kbd>K</kbd> for up) to go through a list of post normally there should be highlighting that shows which post is currently selected. This is not visible in high contrast dark mode.

Here are short demonstrations

[List of question in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r66sD.gif)

[List of questions in high contrast dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNIM1.gif)

[Q&A in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxF56.gif)

[Q&A in high contrast dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUk8D.gif)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Change to high contrast dark mode.
2. Go to a list of questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) or a question ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array)).
3. Press <kbd>J</kbd> to navigate down or <kbd>K</kbd> to navigate up.

System information

- OS: Windows 11
- Browser: Firefox 103